# If body roll of a car is reduced, is the load or weight transfer reduced too?

Tags: car

Will the load transfer or weight transfer be reduced because the body roll is reduced due to stiffening of the suspension ?

Comment: What do you understand by load or weight transfer?

Comment: If I reduce body roll in a car using stiffer suspension, does it mean the weight transfer is reduced?

Comment: Does not answer what I asked...

Answer (score -1):

I think you mean if the overturning moment is reduced. Correct me if I am wrong.

The answer to that is yes.

Regardless of the ways and mechanisms used to restrict the roll of a car, bottom line is that if the downward vector, the sum of the force of mass and centripetal force, or impact force caused by a bump in the road falls outside of the footprint of wheels the car will roll.

So if by the action of a roll bar or stiffened suspension or lowering the CG we can restrict that vector's horizontal component to within an ideal diamond region inside the area delineated by the for wheels, we will have controlled the overturning moment.

** EDIT**

After OP's remark, I thought a diagram will be helpful.

This is a simple diagram showing the cross-section of a car near the rear axel as a basic line diagram of forces.
The two forces acting on CG of the car are its mass contribution to the rear axel, m and centripetal force P. The dashed line represents the axel before it settles under the weight of the car.

As we see the suspension system of the two wheels has to deflect first equally under the mass of the car and then differentially under the overturning moment P* Height of CG, one going down, one up to create a couple of force which its torque will counter the P*H.

But this tilting will create a redistribution of CG by delta which will increase the overturning moment. This is called the P.delta effect. Ultimately the suspension can reach a bifurcation point and will no be stable and will roll. But if we can limit the bending of the suspension we manage to reduce the P*delta effect.

[image: car rolling]

Comment: And there was me trying to find out what the OP understood before jumping in...

Comment: Ahh alright. Kamran, so does the load Transfer occuring while cornering produce body roll or lean then?